# extract pattern from image via python opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, pattern-matching, image-segmentation

I have a bunch of images like this.
[image: the source image]

as we can see from the image, there are two kinds of buildings, the first ones are filled with solid color and the second ones are filled with slashes.

I marked the first kind with green and the second kind with red.

[image: two kinds of buildings]

I think I can extract buildings of the first style with just color masks, but what about the second kind?

I know I might reach the goal by training an image segmentation model, but is it possible to use a pure image processing method to get it?

Comment: Do you want to be able to distinguish between the big and small buildings? or just extract all the building?

Comment: It would be good if I can extract all the buildings and also, distinguish the two kinds. If I can't, I think just extract buildings is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thresholding the image based off of color and then using findContours to get each individual building. Then I'm sorting them by size into either "big building" or "small building" depending on if they're bigger or smaller than the "cutoff" value.

cutoff = 2000

[image]

cutoff = 4000

[image]

cutoff = 6000

[image]

Here's the code I used. You need to press 'q' to move past the first window (it's for clicking on the image to get the color). You can change the building split by modifying the cutoff variable.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# get pixel value under mouse
def clicky(event, x, y, flags, params):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        global img;
        print(img[y][x]);

# load image
img = cv2.imread("town.png");

# find values
cv2.namedWindow("Original");
cv2.setMouseCallback("Original", clicky);
while True:
    cv2.imshow("Original", img);
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break;

# threshold values
# [232 232 238]
mask = cv2.inRange(img, (232, 232, 238), (232, 232, 238));

# erode to get some seperation
kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
mask = cv2.erode(mask,kernel,iterations = 1);

# get contours 
# Opencv 3.4, if using a different major version (4.0 or 2.0), remove the first underscore
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

# filter by size
cutoff = 6000; # change this to change how they are classified
big_contours = [];
small_contours = [];
for contour in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(contour);
    if area > cutoff: 
        big_contours.append(contour);
    else:
        small_contours.append(contour);

# draw contours on mask
colored_mask = np.zeros_like(img);
cv2.drawContours(colored_mask, big_contours, -1, (155, 200, 0), -1);
cv2.drawContours(colored_mask, small_contours, -1, (0, 155, 200), -1);

# show
cv2.imshow("town", img);
cv2.imshow("mask", mask);
cv2.imshow("colored_mask", colored_mask);
cv2.waitKey(0);
```

Edit:

Here's some code for finding the "thin lines" buildings. This method of segmenting by specific color is kinda janky though, especially for these buildings since they don't have one single color.

[image]

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# get pixel value under mouse
def clicky(event, x, y, flags, params):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        global img;
        print(img[y][x]);

# load image
img = cv2.imread("town.png");

# find color values
cv2.namedWindow("Original");
cv2.setMouseCallback("Original", clicky);
while True:
    cv2.imshow("Original", img);
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break;

# set color values
colors = [];
colors.append((227, 228, 228));
colors.append((248, 251, 251));
colors.append((229, 241, 238));
colors.append((240, 242, 242));
colors.append((234, 236, 238));

# threshold values
mask = np.zeros_like(img[:,:,0]);
for color in colors:
    next_mask = cv2.inRange(img, color, color);
    mask = cv2.bitwise_or(mask, next_mask);

# dilate and erode
kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8);
mask = cv2.dilate(mask, kernel, iterations = 5);
mask = cv2.erode(mask, kernel, iterations = 5);

# colored
img[mask == 255] = (155, 200, 0);

# show
cv2.imshow("town", img);
cv2.imshow("mask", mask);
cv2.waitKey(0);
```

Comment: thanks for the work, that looks amazing. But, that's not really what I want... I can't add an image here, so I modify the question for a better explanation. I think the real obstacle lies in extracting blocks of the second style which I marked with red.

Comment: oh, lol. I didn't even see those buildings!

Comment: hahaha, they are ambiguous ~ is there a good way to extract them?

Comment: Clicking around on them show that they also have a unique color. [227 228 228] and [248, 251, 251]. This will get you some of each building as a bunch of lines. You can group lines together into a building based on distance and then draw a minRect around them. I probably won't have time to attempt this tonight.